# ¿Por qué cuando reporto una pregunta para migración solo sale la opción de Meta Stack Overflow en español como destino?

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, reportes, migración

He intentado reportar un par de preguntas, ya que me parece que el tema no pertenece a Stack Overflow en español, sino más bien a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange.

Cuando intento hacerlo, el único posible destino es [Meta Stack Overflow en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com). ¿Por qué? ¿Tiene que ver con la reputación?

Comment: No tiene que ver con la reputación. Te recomiendo que en lugar de votar a cierre, lo publiques como un reporte y así un moderador se encargará de revisarlo.

Comment: Por supuesto, no dudaria en hacer eso. Pero eso significa que un moderador tiene que leer mis comentarios, palabra por palabra, cuando podria solo ver el titulo de la pregunta, ver la sugerencia de migracion y aceptar la accion, reduciendo por mucho el tiempo necesario para moderar y optimizar el sitio. No me tomes a mal, solo se me ocurrio esa pregunta, porque, si esta la opcion, por que no utilizarla.

Comment: ¿Qué destino querías? Si es uno que puede ser necesario en muchos casos, podría incluirse en la ruta de migración. De todos modos, lo dudo porque este es el único sitio en castellano.

Comment: La verdad no habia pensado que el idioma era, en este caso, la limitante a la hora de escojer opciones. Supongo que eso definitivamente responde la pregunta. Si pensamos en esto, una buena sugerencia para el futuro sería que se pudiera migrar a otras páginas y darle la opción al OP para traducir su propia pregunta para que obtuviera la respuesta en otros sitios, que al final eso es lo que vino a buscar.

Comment: Kenny: los moderadores sí pueden migrar a otro sitio. Por ello es que @Luiggi te recomendaba reportar indicándolo. Pero fíjate que es una opción solo en la mano de los moderadores para que haya filtro. Tal y como dije en el anterior comentario, si una ruta se revela necesaria puede plantearse incluirla en los motivos de cierre (por ejemplo, en [so] se puede votar para que una pregunta vaya a [su]). Resumiendo: recomiendo comentar al autor que traduzca y después reportar para que un moderador la mueva, si es pertinente.

Comment: Entiendo. Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Definitivamente todas mis dudas han sido respondidas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como se indicó en los comentarios, las rutas de migración actualmente  configuradas solo permiten mover a Meta.

Desglosemos:

- Los usuarios que tienen el privilegio de [Emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (esto es, usuarios con reputación igual o superior a 3000) pueden sugerir *Cerrar → no relacionado → Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange*. Allí solamente existe Meta.
- Los usuarios que tienen el privilegio de [Reportar publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) (esto es, usuarios con reputación igual o superior a 15) pueden hacer lo mismo yendo a *Reportar → debería ser cerrada... → no relacionado porque... → Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange*. De la misma manera que antes, solo aparece Meta.
- Los moderadores pueden votar por cerrar y en el menú de *Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange* disponen de una opción adicional en la que indicar otro sitio, cualquiera, de la red Stack Exchange.

Por tanto, si consideras que una pregunta debería ser movida a otro sitio de la red, lo mejor que puedes hacer es reportar la publicación indicando el motivo por el cual así lo consideras.

Si esa ruta se convierte en común, entonces se podría debatir en Meta si sería conveniente añadirla en la lista de opciones de cierre para que la migración pueda ser automática. Ejemplos de este tipo hay muchos. Por ejemplo en Stack Overflow hay un motivo que envía la pregunta a Super User; lo hubo a Server Fault pero [se eliminó](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3853/200076).

Un par de notas:

- Dado que la publicación habrá sido enviada a Stack Overflow en español, es probable que esté en castellano. Dado que este y [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) son los únicos en los que se usa este idioma, es necesario que la publicación se cambie al idioma del sitio de destino *antes* de ser migrada. De lo contrario, será rechazada por ese sitio.
- Normalmente los moderadores hablan con los moderadores de otros sitios antes de migrar una pregunta en caso de duda. Facilítales la tarea siendo muy claro y preciso en el reporte con el motivo para solicitar tal migración. Para ello es bueno consultar la sección *What topics can I ask about here?* del sitio de destino.

Lectura recomendada oficial: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/209901)

Comment: ... Y nadie más que el autor debería traducir la pregunta.